# MVC JqGrid Loading Process time solution

Tags: model-view-controller, jqgrid, loading

What is the possible cause of taking Loading... takes time to load jqgrid data. It is slow for sorting, viewing all the records and going to next page (pager to load next page).

I am using IQueryable to create a SQL Query to load data which contains Select Statement with Union Joining all the Query and all the query have buncg of inner joins.

```
Select Statement 
{
 Query with Inner Joins and where clauses
}
Union Select Statement 
{
 Query with Inner Joins and where clauses
}
Union Select Statement 
{
 Query with Inner Joins and where clauses
}
```

Please guide me to find a better solution to load data faster.

Comment: Sorry, but your question don't contains any technical information which can be used to help you: no JavaScript code which shows how you create grid and fill the data, no C# code of the server side, no SQL table structure (ids, indexes use in JOIN, WHERE), no information about Database which you use (MS SQL, MySql and so on), no information about jqGrid version which you use and even no information about the size of tables and the total number of rows which you try to display. Do you tried at least to measure whether the generated SQL statements is slow?

Comment: Tried. But in SQL Server takes less time.

Comment: I have to repeat that **you should be more exact and post more details**. If you write "takes time to load" or "It is slow for sorting" you should better write something like: 20 sec for loading and 10 sec for sorting in your tests. If you write "takes less time" it gives no information too. 9 sec is less as 10 sec and 0.1 sec is less then 10 sec. If you write about sorting it's important to know whether you sort on the client side (`loadonce: true` are used) or not and whether you sort 100, 10000 or 1000000 rows.

Comment: I will soon post more details. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways to do it.

1. Create a different temp folder for all select statement and try to
   run query with inner join.
2. Another is try to increase memory of your server. I had same problem
   and that helps as well.
3. Also check any statement which you add in your query is unwanted
   then remove it.
4. **Main thing** create index.

Comment: Yes you are right. Indexing was the issue. I added index and it worked. I was gonna add my comment a while but forgot to add it.